# Attempted import error: 'GlobalStyles' is not exported from '@material-ui/system' (imported as 'SystemGlobalStyles')

Tags: javascript, reactjs, material-ui, mern

./node_modules/@material-ui/core/GlobalStyles/GlobalStyles.js
Attempted import error: 'GlobalStyles' is not exported from '@material-ui/system' (imported as 'SystemGlobalStyles').

I'm facing this problem and I can't understand in which file it's occuring.

Comment: Post the context and your code. This is just an error message

Comment: Actually, I was not able to understand from which file the error is coming from so that's why didn't post anything related to the code over here, I thought that there might be someone else who might face this problem so he can get a solution over here for it.

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution to this question.

1. Delete `@material-ui` folder from `node_modules`.
2. Run `npm i @mui/material` in the terminal.
3. Check for the correct spellings in the import statement. It should be `from "@material-ui/core"`;

This worked for me! :)